# ROR + Ransack: FIlter results by range of numbers (age categories)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I'm trying to allow filter criteria by age categories using Ransack. However, i do not have age category as part of the articles table, but as a method in articles model. I have referenced this other

I want users to be able to filter articles with created_at dates belonging to an age category, however, i cant seem to understand why the options_for_select list for selecting the age category is not being rendered at all. When i checked in the rails console, there is not content between the div tag.

However, the dropdown list for options_from_collection_for_select is rendered.

**schema:**

```
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**browse.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <%= f.select :categories_name_cont, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name", @q.categories_name_eq), 
                                                                            { :prompt => "Any Category" },
                                                                            { class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <% f.select :age_group_in, options_for_select([["more than 1 year ago", "more than 1 year ago"],
                                                    ["less than 1 year ago", "less than 1 year ago"],
                                                    ["less than 3 months ago", "less than 3 months ago"],
                                                    ["less than 1 month ago", "less than 1 month ago"]]), 
                                                    { :prompt => "Any Age Group" }, 
                                                    { class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**articles controller**

```
def browse
  @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])
  @articles_morefilter = @q.result.includes(:categories, :users)
end
```

**model: article.rb**

```
  def age_group
    months_between = Date.today.month - self.created_at.month
    if months_between > 12
        "more than 1 year ago"
    elsif months_between  <= 12
        "less than 1 year ago"
    elsif months_between  <= 3
        "less than 3 months ago"
    elsif months_between <= 1
        "less than 1 month ago"
    end
  end

ransacker :age_group, :formatter => proc {|v| Date.today.month - v.created_at.month} do |parent|
  parent.table[:created_at]
end
```

**EDIT: I fixed it by adding = after <% to render the field.** I am now getting a new error, seems that there is a problem with the Ransacker syntax.

```
PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "less than 1 month ago"
LINE 1: ...name" ILIKE '%1%' AND "articles"."created_at" IN ('less than...
```

When i test changing `parent.table[:created_at]` to `parent.table[:age_group]`, i get this error instead:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column articles.age_group does not exist
LINE 1: ...ry_id" WHERE ("categories"."name" ILIKE '%3%' AND "articles"...
```

Comment: You forgot the `=` (equal sign) `<% f.select :age_group_in,#... %>` should be `<%= f.select :age_group_in,#... %>`. There are likely other issues with your `ransacker` but this is why the drop down doesn't render.

Comment: @engineersmnky that was careless of me. yes, there is a problem with my ransacker syntax as i am now getting the above error after i click submit.

Comment: Yeah I figured but I think you should probably think about your logic a bit as well. For example at what point do you expect `months_between` to be greater than 12 and how do you expect your third and forth conditions to ever apply? right now `months_between` has a maximum range of 0-11 (because `DateTime#month` will return 1-12) and the second condition is `<= 12` which will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `ransacker` like so

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

  ransacker :age_group do |parent| 
    query= <<-SQL 
       CASE ((DATE_PART('year', CURRENT_DATE) - DATE_PART('year', #{parent.table[:created_at].to_sql})) * 12 +
          (DATE_PART('month', CURRENT_DATE) - DATE_PART('month', #{parent.table[:created_at].to_sql})))
         WHEN 0,1 THEN "less than 1 month ago"
         WHEN 2,3 THEN "less than 3 months ago"
         WHEN 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 THEN "less than 1 year ago"
         ELSE "more than 1 year ago"
       END
    SQL 
    Arel.sql(query)
  end
```

And then change  `:age_group_in` in your view to `:age_group_eq`. This answer assumes `postgres` if you are using something like `MSSQL` then the `CASE` potion is simplified to `DATEDIFF(m,#{parent.table[:created_at]},GETDATE())`.

This lacks daily accuracy but I think it is close enough for your usage

Comment: I get 2 error: 1) syntax error: unexpected end-of-input, 2( can't find string "SQL" anywhere before EOF in the editor itself.

Comment: @diana are you sure you used exactly what I posted including the `SQL` before `Arel.sql(query)`? works fine in [this Gist](https://repl.it/MZUM/1)

Comment: yeah.. it works now after i copied and pasted again, but strange this is happening...https://screenshots.firefox.com/qYIxobvqy3jy49D8/ide.c9.io, i am now getting an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error --> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Arel"
LINE 1: ...year', CURRENT_DATE) - DATE_PART('year', #<struct Arel::Attr...

Comment: @diana that was my mistake updated now. You could also just change the `parent.table[:created_at]` to articles.created_at